# Append new data to entity in Datomic

Tags: clojure, insert, datomic

In trying to update database tag data on posts I have a function that looks like

```
(defn add-tag-to-post [eid email tags]
  (d/transact conn [{:db/id eid,
                     :author/email email,
                     :post/tag tags}]))
```

Unfortunately, this does not preserve tags (unless I were to query by time).  I would like to simply append to the tags list instead of write a new one.

Example:

```
{:title "Straight edges", 
 :content "fold instead of tearing it.  ", 
 :tags "scissor-less edges", ;;check out these awesome tags
 :author "me@website.hax"
 :eid 1759}  


(add-tag-to-post 1759 "me@website.hax" "art")
;;desired behavior: adds tag "art" to the list of tags

(get-post-by-eid 1759)
;;returns 

{:title "Straight edges", 
 :content "fold instead of tearing it.  ", 
 :tags "art", ;;not cumulative tag addition ;/
 :author "me@website.hax"
 :eid 1759}
```

How can this be achieved?

Does it make more sense to simply query over the lifetime of the entity instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to make your `:post/tag` attribute have `:cardinality/many` - see `:db/cardinality` in http://docs.datomic.com/schema.html.

By default, attributes have `:cardinality/one` which automatically retracts old values when they are overwritten. `:cardinality/many` cancels out that behaviour.